# Onload remove radio button value

Tags: javascript, html

How to remove a Radio button value on onload of page..here is the list of radio button so dynamically i have to remove this value `<input type="radio" name=myradio value="Null">Null`

```
<input type="radio" name=myradio value="Bill">one
<input type="radio" name=myradio value="Sale">two
<input type="radio" name=myradio value="Null">Null
```

Comment: You want to remove the radio button or you want to erase the value?

Comment: can you explain it further?

Comment: if (Bill[i].innerHTML == "Null Value" || Bill[i].innerHTML == "")

Comment: I need to remove if radio button contain value equal value="Null"

Comment: Do you wish to remove the radio button itself or just the value ?

Comment: Yes i want a  remove a particular  radio button if it contain like Null

Answer (score 1):

You can try this- first make a Javascript function like:

```
<script>
    function remvalue()
        {
    document.getElementById('myradiobutton').value="";

    }
window.onload=remvalue;
</script>
```

And then assign the ID to the radio button:

```
<input type="radio" id=myradiobutton name=myradio value="Null">Null
```

Comment: You cannot assign the same ID to multiple elements. It removes the value of the radio button, not the actual text standing to the right of it. alexP's script is working fine, use his answer

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function() {
    var myradios= document.getElementsByName('myradio'); //Get all myradio elements from document

    for (var i = 0; i < myradios.length; i++) { //Loop all myradio elements
        if (myradios[i].value == 'Null') { //If value of element == null
            myradios[i].parentNode.removeChild(myradios[i].nextSibling); //Removes the "Null"-Text
            myradios[i].parentNode.removeChild(myradios[i]); //Removes the radio button
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>[JSfiddle DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/hRSYj/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Below script will remove the radio button with value null.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='radio'][name='myradio'][value='Null']").remove();
});
```